# Xamarin location.Speed runtime errors

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, location, runtime-error

I'm getting runtime errors and crashing when trying to implement location.Speed into my Xamarin android app.

Heres a snippet of the code  -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;

namespace SpeedoMeter
{
   [Activity(Label = "SpeedoMeter", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    Location currentLocation;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String locationProvider;
    TextView txtLocation;
    TextView txtCoords;
    TextView txtSpeed;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        //getting ui elements
        TextView txtSpeed = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSpeed);
        txtCoords = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCoords);
        txtLocation = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLoc);
        txtSpeed = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSpeed);



        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.buttonGetLoc).Click += AddressButton_OnClick;
        Button btnGetLocation = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonGetLoc);


        InitializeLocationManager();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }



    async void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        if (currentLocation == null)
        {
            txtCoords.Text = "Cannot determine current location";
            return;
        }

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        IList<Address> addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(currentLocation.Latitude, currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

        Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
        if (address != null)
        {
            StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
            {
                deviceAddress.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
                             .AppendLine(",");
            }
            txtLocation.Text = deviceAddress.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtLocation.Text = "Unable to determine the address.";
        }

    }


    void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);

        Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
        {
            Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
        };

        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            locationProvider = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        currentLocation = location;
        if (currentLocation == null)
        {
            txtCoords.Text = "Unable to determine your location.";
        }
        else
        {
            txtCoords.Text = String.Format("{0},{1}", currentLocation.Latitude, currentLocation.Longitude);
            txtSpeed.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", currentLocation.Speed, " mph");
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
}
```

everything runs okay, until I add this line :

```
            txtSpeed.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", currentLocation.Speed, " mph");
```

Even when storing the speed into a float, same issue.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where would you be adding the line (in which method, after which statements, etc.)? Or are you referring to the line in OnLocationChanged(Location location)?

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed it just now.  Problem was I was initializing the txtSpeed twice.